# Displaying image URL after submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form where the user submits an image and after submission the image URL will be shown in an input text field. The form data is relayed to PHP through Ajax. The image is then uploaded to the server. I have implemented the submission system, but I do not know how I can display the uploaded URL in the input text field so the user can see it. I do not want the page to refresh, this all happens dynamically.

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<form class="image_upload" method="post" action="">
    <input name="server_upload" type="file">
     <input type="text" name="image_url" readonly>
    <input type="submit" value="UPLOAD TO SERVER">
</form>
```

**jQuery/Ajax**

```
$('.image_upload').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        if ($('.image_upload').valid())
        {

            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '',
              data: new FormData(this),
              processData: false,
              contentType: false,
              success: function(data) {

              }
            })
     }
 })
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_FILES["server_upload"]))
    {
        $name = $_FILES["server_upload"]["name"];
        $tempName = $_FILES["server_upload"]["tmp_name"];
        $target_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/stories/media/images/$name";
        if (getimagesize($target_file) == true)
        {
            $ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);     
            $name = basename($name, "." . $ext);
            $name = $name . uniqid() . "." . $ext;
            $target_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/stories/media/images/$name";
        }

        move_uploaded_file($tempName, $target_file);
    }
```

I want $target_file to be shown in the input text form field after the user submits an image. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: you can use sessions which is one option and set it to a variable/session array and in a conditional statement in the input value

Comment: @Fred-ii- How can a session be outputted in an input text field without there being a page refresh?

Comment: output whatever you need from your PHP function, maybe `echo $target_file` - read it in your AJAX function (it'll be `data` in your `success:` code) ... do things with `data` to display what you need where you need it ... or rather than figuring it out for yourself from the general hints, just use the answer posted - which does exactly what you want

Comment: @JaromandaX When I do this, my PHP code is being outputted instead of $target_file for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option you have is to echo `$target_file` after the line

```
move_uploaded_file($tempName, $target_file);
echo $target_file;
```

Then in your ajax success, you can use this like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '',                      // (*)
    data: new FormData(this),
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $('input[name=image_url]').val(data);
    }
});
```

As long as the form submission doesn't take you to another page, the `data` will be what you echoed.

**(*) Notes:**

- Since the `url` is empty, which by default is the current page, the above code would return the entire page. If you put the PHP into another file and call that like `url: 'file.php'`, it will function correctly.

Comment: For some reason when I do this, it's displaying all my HTML code in the input box

Comment: It must be because the `url` is empty, which by default is the current page, thus you're returning the entire page. If you put the php into another file and call that in the `url` above like `url: 'file.php',` it will return correctly.

Comment: When I do this, all the PHP code in the file is being echo'd out

Comment: Can you make a pastebin of your new code or something so we can see what your latest codes are?

Comment: Lines 1-17 should be in a different file, say ajax.php and line 32 is still an empty url where it should've been `url: 'yourFileName.php'` as I mentioned above.

Comment: @ekn Sorry, I forgot to update that. I've tried this, but it's still doing the same thing

Comment: The only case I can think that ajax returns the url's entire php code is the PHP not working properly thus ajax requests and reads as html. You should confirm php is installed and working properly. Sure you have a working webserver to parse/run php?

Comment: PHP needs the server to process it's directives. Without a server ajax would just return whatever was written in the file.

Comment: @Ekn My PHP is working properly because everything I do in PHP works. I think the problem is the Ajax code, it's not taking the input correctly...

Comment: Can you print the $_POST array in the php file to see what data it gets? Does the file upload bit, or any part of that php file work?

Comment: @Ekn Everything works, when I select an image and upload the image gets sent to the server successfully. I've been working in PHP for a while, I just don't understand how Ajax works at receiving PHP data

Comment: @Ekn I have found out my mistake. It was because I didn't include PHP tags in my PHP file. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Oh I see, well, I'm glad you spotted :)